# Detecting GamePad/Joystick movement, Keypress inside other application

Tags: python

I want to detect the key press on Gamepad. I tried searching for module that controls the keyboard movement, but no luck, so I switched to Gamepad movement which seems to have same problem. Can  I detect the joystick key presses/ movements on other  application? Like GTA5 ? FIFA ? PUBG?

I tried using the pygame, but it detects only the movement inside the pygame window, but not external. Any help ?